# Paginate Custom Post, Old and New buttons not displaying

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I am trying to paginate my custom post to have multiple pages once a limit of posts is met per page. The end goal is to have the url have /page=2 etc. I have set the limit to one post per page to test (currently have two posts) but the old and new buttons at the bottom are not showing up? What am I doing wrong?

```
    <div class="col-md-8">

    <!-- set up or arguments for our custom query -->
    <?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    $query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'news',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'paged' => $paged
    ); ?>

    <?php $news = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'news'
        ));  ?>
    <?php while($news->have_posts()) : $news->the_post(); ?>
        <h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
        </h2>
        <p class="lead">
            <?php $author = get_the_author(); ?>
            by <?php echo $author ?>
        </p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Posted on <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></p>
        <hr>
        <a href="#">
            <?php if( get_field('image') ): ?>
            <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" alt="">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
        <hr>

        <?php if(get_field('news_content')): ?>
            <p class="description"><?php echo get_field('news_content'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>

        <hr>


    <?php endwhile ?>

        <!-- Pager -->
        <?php if ($news->max_num_pages > 1) { ?>
        <ul class="pager">
            <li class="previous">
                <a href="<?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?>">&larr; Older</a>
            </li>
            <li class="next">
                <a href="<?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); ?>">Newer &rarr;</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to adapt the code from the Codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query to fit your own query:

```
        <a href="<?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $news->max_num_pages ); ?>">&larr; Older</a>
```